Priority inversion when assigning PHLivePhoto in NSViewRepresentable
I want to use PHLivePhotoView in SwiftUI on macOS:
struct LivePhotoView: NSViewRepresentable {
    var livephoto: PHLivePhoto

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> PHLivePhotoView {
        return PHLivePhotoView()
    }

    func updateNSView(_ lpView: PHLivePhotoView, context: Context) {
        lpView.livePhoto = livephoto // <-- Hang Risk Warning
    }
}

When I run this the UI is laggy and I get a run-time hang risk warning:

[Internal] Thread running at User-interactive quality-of-service class waiting on a lower QoS thread running at Default quality-of-service class. Investigate ways to avoid priority inversions

I've tried wrapping the assignment in different DispatchQueues but can't get rid of the warning (and the hangs).
Does anyone have an idea about what to do?
